# What is the format of a Google blogger post GUID? PHP / CodeIgniter / SimplePie

Tags: php, codeigniter, rss, blogger, simplepie

I'm trying to create pages on my site which display RSS google blogger posts. I'm using PHP, CodeIgniter, and SimplePie to parse the Google feeds.

**Issue 1:**

I want to be able to create a link using the guid on one page and then display the invidual blog post on the next page. So I have something like this:

http://mysite.co.uk/technology/blog_post/tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-6168323340908483477.post-1651486241197422269

This doesn't work as the guid is not valid for urls and looks a mess (could use url_encode but don't want to). I wanted to get it like this:

http://mysite.co.uk/technology/blog_post/6168323340908483477/1651486241197422269

To do this I need to understand the format of the guid. Is this a json object? If so how do I go about splitting this? I can use explode() to split it but I imagine there's a better way of doing it.

**Issue 2:**

I can display the feeds on my CodeIgniter / SimplePie site just fine but I can't display an individual feed easily. Here is my code at the moment (untested):

```
  foreach($feeds as $k => $item):
    if(  $item->get_id()==$this->uri->segment(3) ): //Does id of post match id passed in?
    ?>
      <h1 id="main-heading"><?=$page_title?></h1>
      <div class="blog-date"><?=$item->get_date()?></div>
      <h3><a href="<?=$item->get_link()?>"><?=$item->get_title()?></a></h3>
      <div class="blog-desc"><?=$item->get_description()?></div>
    <?
    break;//End as we only want to display one post, need a better way of doing this.
    endif;
  endforeach;
```

Obviously this is a loop and not an individual reference to 1 feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Question 1

You shouldn't rely on the GUID being a certain format, nor should you rely on it being a valid URL (unless the `isPermalink` attribute is set to `true` - omitted is supposed to imply `true`, but that's not always the case).

Your best bet is to simply hash the GUID. If you want SimplePie to do that for you, just use [`$item->get_id(true)`](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_item/get_id)

#### Question 2

If you're only trying to use one feed, then you should only be passing that one into SimplePie, rather than using the multifeeds technique. (It's possible in the future that we'll introduce a `SimplePie_Feed` class separate to `SimplePie`, allowing you to loop over each feed individually, but this doesn't yet exist.)

Comment: Great advice thanks. I'll use the hashed version as suggested. Don't know why I wasn't just passing in one feed, seems easy now.

Answer (score -1):

This may interest you [pipes by Yahoo](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/)

> Pipes is a powerful composition tool to aggregate, manipulate, and
>   mashup content from around the web.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't really answer my question.